# Get atrribute from javascript variable of jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get the attribute of my control as below :

```
var $checkboxObj = $("#chk-" + id);
alert($checkboxObj.attr('id'));
```

but I receive nothing even popup message.

Please help me, thanks in advance!!

=================

It should work as my new testing, maybe I need to recheck somewhere else. Following is successfully tested snippet:

```
var $myCtrl = $("#output");
$myCtrl.html($myCtrl.attr('id'));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzq20jdf/)

Keeping investigation!

Comment: Something else is wrong...

Comment: when I comment out this snippet code, everything else go well...:(

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should check your browser console to see if any issue has occurred before the alert event. My guess will be id is not defined.

Comment: @Runcorn — That would not prevent `alert`

Comment: @kembedded Please see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9kcb3jc/) I have created for the given code. Try to reproduce the problem in there with your relevant code. After that, hit "update" and send the new link.

Comment: @nkmol thanks. I am not familiar with jsFiddle but your code help me a lot :)

Comment: @Rayon It would actually. Try this on your end var `$checkboxObj = $("#passwor" + id); alert("pawal");`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my problem. I don't know exactly why it is relevant with cache. After clear my cookies, cache, offline data, it works again without any modification.

Comment: Hey, you can post such additional information as edit in your original post, as this is not an answer but just extra information for your question. Does your JsFiddle now actually work?

Comment: @nkmol Oh thanks, I have updated the post content. The remaining answer is why it is related with cache, cookies or offline data? Don't know why it is related with JS...

Comment: Really weird. Let us know (by comment @) if the problem is back :) Goodluck further on!